# Append an environment variable to another one with export

Tags: bash, shell

I want to append a previously exported string to a new one, so that:

```
export TAG=img
export FILENAME=$TAG_001.jpg
```

The result I'd like to obtain is `$FILENAME=img_001.jpg`, but the export processes it as `$TAG_001` instead of `$TAG`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
export FILENAME=${TAG}_001.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

On my BASH: `GNU bash, wersja 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

This also works:

```
$ export FILENAME="$TAG"_001.jpg
$ echo $FILENAME
```

> img_001.jpg